# How to Convert Oracle Stored Procedure Output to CSV file

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have seen many examples where you can convert a SQL Query output to a CSV file by calling it from a stored procedure as shown in PL/SQL code below. However, in my case, I have a stored procedure called Management with 3 input parameters. Once these inputs are confirmed, the stored procedure extracts the result with 10 columns based on the code in the PL/SQL.

My aim is to convert this extract from the Management stored procedure to a CSV. The examples I found so far are all to do with converting SQL query only to CSV by calling it from a stored procedure.

I'm trying to avoid writing the code to convert the output to CSV in the Management stored procedure by calling it from another stored procedure. Is this possible?

The Management stored procedure is called by the SQL developer and the values are returned by applying a select query from two tables and applying multiple cases and if statements.

An example will be much appreciated.

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_to_csv
    IS
       v_file     UTL_FILE.file_type;
       v_string   VARCHAR2 (4000);
    
       CURSOR c_emp
       IS
          SELECT empno,
                 ename,
                 deptno,
                 sal,
                 comm
            FROM emp;
    BEGIN
       v_file :=
          UTL_FILE.fopen ('CSVDIR',
                          'empdata.csv',
                          'w',
                          1000);
    
       -- if you do not want heading then remove below two lines
       v_string := 'Emp Code, Emp Name, Dept, Salary, Commission';
       UTL_FILE.put_line (v_file, v_string);
    
       FOR cur IN c_emp
       LOOP
          v_string :=
                cur.empno
             || ','
             || cur.ename
             || ','
             || cur.deptno
             || ','
             || cur.sal
             || ','
             || cur.comm;
    
          UTL_FILE.put_line (v_file, v_string);
    
       END LOOP;
       UTL_FILE.fclose (v_file);
    
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          IF UTL_FILE.is_open (v_file)
          THEN
             UTL_FILE.fclose (v_file);
          END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: How are you calling the `Management` stored procedure, and how is it returning values? Please edit your question and explain this **in the question**.

Comment: @ Bob Jarvis, sorry not sure about your question about how I'm returning the value but I hope I answered it in my edit question.

Comment: But is it a procedure that has multiple OUT arguments, or an OUT ref cursor, or a dbms_sql return; or is it just printing things with `dbms_output`; or is it a function that returns a ref cursor or a pipelined table? Please edit your question to at least gives the procedure spec (but preferably what it does internally for context); and an example of what it gives and what form that takes.

Answer (score 0):

The management SP will return values and you will use those values to create the CSV file with this new SP (export_to_csv)? If this is the case then

1. Create one Package Spec and define 2 SPs (Management and export_to_csv).
2. Then in the Package body, copy the logic of Management sp and at the end of Management SP, call your new SP (export_to_csv).
3. If you already have Package then directly use that package instead of creating the new one.